# Intellisense is not working in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, intellisense

I'm using SQL Server 2008 in my system. I have a database with some tables. When I type a query like:

```
Select * from Tblname
```

in query window, the table names from the database are not listed. When I type a query like:

```
 Select COUNT(Id) from Table1
```

after I type `Select` it does not list out the default keywords like COUNT,SUM., etc

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you mean Intellisense, not Initialization. What result do you get if you run `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: Yes you are right... Intellisense is correct... When i run this above query, the result will be `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6001: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)`

Comment: Are you using Management Studio, or some other utility to connect to your db? If are using SSMS, what happens if you go to `Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache` ?

Comment: yes i'm using Management studio... After `Refresh Local Cache`, it's not working....

Comment: I followed all the things, which is Pinal dave gave in the given below site.. `http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/31/sql-server-2008-intellisense-does-not-work-enable-intellisense/`.. but it does not working in my management studio..

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju From the same site that you're about to [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/31/sql-server-2008-intellisense-does-not-work-enable-intellisense/) (top Google result!) did you see one of the other suggestions from the comments:

`Verify that the T-SQL Editor does not launch in SQLCMD mode Under Tools->Options->Query Execution->SQL Server->General, make sure “By default, open new queries in SQLCMD mode” is unchecked`

Comment: @Bridge : I tried that option also, but it does not working...

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you did not select the database containing the table from the available databases drop-down at the top left.

Another way to check this is to use databaseName.dbo.Tblname to make sure you are referencing the database with that table in it.